VS code debugger "Step Over" function bug: have to press "step over" multiple times before actually stepping over + more weird behaviour
In VS code while debugging I have to press "step over" multiple times before actually stepping over a line, sometimes as many times as 10.
It also sometimes bugs and considers the application running after a "step over" but it is not.
This is a video of the problem (20 seconds). At the end of the video you can see that I press "step over" 7-8 times and I am still unable to go over a simple if statement. Also sometimes I have to press "pause" even when the code is not running or it won't hit the next line/breakpoint
gif of the problem 
Code is unoptimized, -g flag is there, code was just rebuilt with Ctrl+Shift+B. Software has no threading.
my build file
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file by me",
            "command": "D:\\0-Software\\MSYS2\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-Wall",
                "-Werror", 
                "-O0",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"

            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"

my launch configuration
      {
            "name": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\0-Software\\MSYS2\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        }

Is it my setup? Maybe I set up something wrong in the C extension of VS Code? It recently wasn't able to find the standard libraries so I had to add the compiler path and the intellisense inside the C Extension Configuration

If you run gdb directly without involving VSCode, do you still have the same problem? It helps to narrow down the problem.

@TedLyngmo Just finished trying it and it worked perfectly fine from console

Brilliant! If you ever have to file a bugreport to the VSCode team, that is one important fact to give them.

Yeah I guess that's all I can do. It always feels kinda hopeless to be the only person to have a certain bug tho

You probably aren't, but few people write bugreports. I try to make it as quick and painless as possible. Write the report - download the source if it's open, see if I can fix it, upload a patch - hope for the best. Meanwhile, I use my patched version. As long as it's open, there is hope - and I think VSCode source is open, but I don't use it myself.

FWIW: it might be the case that the “step over” is stepping over instructions  rather than lines. That would indeed be a bug if you’re stepping in a source code view, but it could at least explain the cause of your problem.

Is there a log that shows what command is sent from VScode to gdb when stepping?
